# SQL Server 2014 - DB mail sending Issue

Tags: email, sql-server-2014

DB mail was working fine using SQL Server 2014; however since we moved our email to Office365 online Exchange, we are having issue. Whenever there are rapidly generated emails by our application; then sending emails is stopped with following message:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2018-04-08T08:25:06).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.)

Service again starts sending emails automatically after a lag of few hours.

I have already checked email account separately and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limit set by `Office 365`. Check this image captured from [microsoft technet post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx)

[image: img]

Based on your subscription, limits are there for sending total emails per day as well as bulk email at a time. Same has been confirmed in this [Microsoft blog question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_o365b/sending-bulk-mass-emails-using-office-365-outlook/3ec04ca2-416a-40fe-af37-077f3267698d)

That's why your task stops sending email for sometime to reset its Recipient limit.

Comment: I am checking my system in relation to above information. So far seems to be this issue will be resolved, problem was with Office 365 Limits